# Filling detail form using Jmeter and blazemeter for 500 concurent users

Tags: testing, jmeter, blazemeter

I am new in jmeter and doing R&D on Jmeter. I have a scenario can you help me with this, 1. there is detailed form filling which 1000 users have to fill out at the same time 2. I am using Blaze meter to record the submissions 3. I know about CSV file but I am not able to find the name, and email var in those files recorded by the blaze meter so I can pass the date from the CSV 4. In last even if these all work can I see all submissions in the response (backend)    form link: https://testapp-app.kloudsoft.co/survey/38e288e2-7957-4a05-b024-fb337df2f0f6

Answer (score 0):

It's weird because I was able to locate the inputs immediately:

[image]

However there is one thing which will prevent you from replaying the recorded script even after parameterization: this `authenticity_token` parameter which needs to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

[image]

You will need to find it in one of the previous responses, extract it using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replace recorded hard-coded value with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) from the Post-Processor.

The same applies to the `guest_token` parameter and most probably to `project_id` and `survey_link_id` as they might change in the future.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

Comment: How are you able to record... I am not seeing anything via HTTP test recorder in chrome. And If I am using blazemeter for recording will it be a useful?